# Team Foundation Server build issue

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfsbuild

I have problem with Team Foundation Server 2010 and Visual Studio.

When I'm in offline mode the project builds very quickly but when I'm in online mode with TFS my project builds very slowly. When I stop the project it waits a long time.

Any idea what might be causing the problem?